# Youtube processing stuck at 95%

Tags: youtube, ffmpeg, mp4, h.264, codec

Well I'm trying to upload a video recorded with ffmpeg, but Youtube fail at processing it.

Here's the video information:

[image]

[image]
Here's the link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7XlxLh0usnY.

Comment: ?? - It's live at Youtube.

Comment: @Mulvya Sorry. I didn't understand the question. The video is recorded using ffmpeg and after that I upload the video.

Comment: The video has been published - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kloa9edSKZg

Comment: @Mulvya I have get wrong images, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

It turn's out that the problem in my case was the video stream and audio stream had differente lenghts. Always the video was shorter than the audio.

I had to use ffmpeg to make both streams with the same lenght.

Comment: We could have provided this answer for you years ago if you would have provided the actual ffmpeg command you used and the complete log from the command. We ask for this for most ffmpeg questions.

Comment: That's the point. I did not know where be could the error. And as you can see nobody tried nothing. Not my fault.